# How to redirect SFDC URL clicked outside SFDC to open as a primary tab in Salesforce Console if user has an active session in Salesforce Console?

Tags: service-cloud-console, url, console

While waiting for my Idea [Open Salesforce URLs in emails, chats, etc. in existing Salesforce Console](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnA9AAK) to gather 10k votes, I'd like to understand how best to force a Salesforce URL clicked from an email, chat message, etc., to open on a primary tab in the *existing* Salesforce Console if the user has an active session in the console.

Current behaviour opens the link on a new browser tab, even if the URL is in the console-style format. SFDC confirms this is working as intended, but that doesn't make it desirable: click three links and you end up with three consoles in three browser tabs, defeating the purpose of the console.

Would this best be tackled as a Chrome extension, using Visualforce to handle the redirect, or via another approach? It's important to maintain robust security.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Scott, I am, in fact, working on a browser extension to provide this capability. From your comment, it sounds like you use Google Chrome. Correct me if you are interested in other browser. I will keep you posted. Other viewers: if you are interested, please comment on which browser is preferable.

Comment: Yes,  our users are mostly using Chrome so that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Chrome Extension out there which address this sad issue, called 'Click-to-Console': [Link Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-to-console/aciejfpenmfodekmppiehcbcgkjigjhl).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does seem to do the trick - thanks for the tip! The current permissions level ('Read and change your data on all websites you visit') is probably enough to shoot it down from a security point of view. I wonder if the desired redirection could not be achieved with narrower permissions.

Comment: Just a note that this extension was created by a Salesforce employee. It's not official or supported, but that should help with security concerns. I don't think it could be done without those permissions, since it would have to read and control other web tabs in order to close them and open as a console tab.