# Link to open object as a tab in Lightning

Tags: lightning, email-template

We recently migrated to Lightning, and we have internal email alert, which has a link to the Case obejct in the following syntax:

```
Case #:&nbsp;<a href="https://my-company.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/{!Case.Id}/view">{!Case.CaseNumber}</a>
```

[image]

When our Support Agents click this link, it is opening a new Browser tab with Lightning. 
I wonder if it would be possible to enforce the browser to open the link as a tab inside the existing Lightning active browser tab session?

Comment: Where does that link seat?Also - where is your "Lightning active tab" ? Best practice for opening a url is through lightning component and use `force:navigateToURL` or `force:navigateToSObject` or `force:navigateToComponent`

Comment: Thanks Itai.  This link is part of an internal Email notification - i.e a custom 'case assignment' email message, intended for internal audience. I am not able to include 'force' or Apex commands.

Comment: So is it an email alert?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In the 'old' service console, I was able to achieve this (opening the link in the email as a Service Console tab) with a Google Chrome Extension, see my reply to the following question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72611/how-to-redirect-sfdc-url-clicked-outside-sfdc-to-open-as-a-primary-tab-in-salesf/150223#150223

Comment: OK, I think your question is not clear enough - where do you create a link, how, where do you want to open it? please provide code and exact details here in the question, if you want someone to look at it and think about a good answer

Comment: Thank Itai. I added additional information, and hope this elaboration helps in understanding the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now I understand your request. Does a relative url help?  `<a href="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!Case.Id}/view">{!Case.CaseNumber}</a>`

Comment: Thanks.  Trying out a relative url, results a 'Redirect Notice' (see here - https://www.screencast.com/t/ol4RvuELce).